# Redirection Depending Upon Url Parameter

Tags: php

Looking For A Php Code To redirect To a specific Url Depending upon Paramter

```
redirect.php?mid=1
```

Should Redirect to page1.php

```
redirect.php?mid=2
```

Should Redirect to Page2.php

And If url is without parameter

```
redirect.php
```

should redirect to page3.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

// quesry string parameters are accessible through $_GET or $_REQUEST
switch($_GET['mid']) // Look only at mid parameter. Decide what to do based on value
{
    case 1: 
        $page = 'page1.php'; // Save the redirection to a variable
        break;
    case 2:
        $page = 'page2.php';
        break;
    default:
        $page = 'page3.php';
        break;
}

// redirect to correct page
header('location: '. $page); 

?>
```

[$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) -- get querystring params

[switch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) -- Switch control structure

[header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) -- redirect

Comment: it's harsh to not upvote your answer or to give OP a chance to finally do his job himself? ;-)

Comment: I personally like leaving complete solutions so that not only the OP has a valid working example to learn from but so that others in the future who might stumble on this for a different reason, have what they need to solve their problems.

Comment: "php redirect" --- there are **thousands** of relevant results in the google. OP is just lazy to do that (or may be banned by google, who knows)